# Customize image field in forms, django

Tags: python, django

The template .html

```
{{form.image}}
```

models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="data", null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
image = forms.FileField()
```

The uploading is working but it is showing uncorrectly like this
https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TLMTH8LJY-F02L2EZ70KH/screen_shot_2021-11-08_at_10.02.11_am.png

I want to show only img tag and the input type file to change it

Thanks in advance!